# Removed components still having an effect on later draw functions

Tags: java, applet, components

I'm trying to get 2 classes to interact with the same Graphics object but removing a Button component on the 1st class creates an empty space where it used to be after drawRect() is called in the 2nd class.

I have tried a combination of validate(), revalidate() and repaint() in both classes.

1st class:

```
    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import testpackage.testing_draw_class;

    public class testing_class_draw_main extends Applet implements ActionListener {
        Button b;
        testing_draw_class test;
        Graphics g;
        public void init() {
            b = new Button("test now!");
            add(b);
            b.addActionListener(this);

            test = new testing_draw_class();
            g = getGraphics();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            remove(b);  // removes button
            revalidate();
            test.paint(g);
        }
    }
```

2nd class:

```
    package testpackage;

    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class testing_draw_class extends Applet {
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
        }
    }
```

I was expecting a complete black square however there is a gap where the removed button used to be.
[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjwaJ.png)

Comment: Could you please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @WJS I have added the additional code.

Comment: I'm not certain what the problem is.  When I use `setBackground(Color.Black)` it seems to work as desired.  But I would stay away from applets and use `JFrames` and `JPanels` as just about everything involving Applets has been deprecated since `Java 9`.  Check out the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more on painting with Swing components.